# Copy the a resolved git merge to another merge

Tags: git

In my git workflow i have to merge a `feature` branch into `master`.
However while i am resolving merge conflicts, somebody has pushed a new commit to `feature` and `master`.

I have then to generate a new merge commit, based on `new feature` and `new master`. However 90 % of the merge conflicts are still the same.
So my question is. Can i save my progress from the `first merge`, and apply it in the conflict phase of the `new merge` ?

```
 +--------+        +--------+             +------------+
 |        |        |        |             |            |
 |  init  +------> | master +-----------> | new master |
 |        |        |        |             |            |
 +--------+        +--------+             +------------+
       |                 |                             |
       |           +---------+            +-------------+
       |           |         |            |             |
       +---------> | feature +----------> | new feature |
                   |         |            |             |
                   +---------+            +-------------+
                    |    |                            ||
                    |    |                            ||
                    |    |      +----------------+    ||        +-----------+
                    |    +----> |                |    +--------->           |
                    |           |   first merge  |    |         | new merge |
                    +----------->                |    +--------->           |
                                +----------------+              +-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has a feature called rerere. It can be used at this situation.
Enable rerere in config file and it just works.
I think it is the right way to resolve this problem.

https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

To use this feature without enabling it in advance, the script https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/rerere-train.sh can help you.

Maybe there is a simple method to do it.
Merge `new feature` to `first merge` and then merge the result to `new master`.

Comment: I will have a look at git-rerere. I could solve it with an additional merge, but i don't want to create so much merge commits.

Comment: rerere won't reduce the number of merges, it will only potentially reduce the number of merge conflicts you need to manually handle.